# Understanding little-o and big-o intuitively?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, intuition

We have that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^a}{b^x} = 0, \quad a > 0, \quad b > 1$$

So we say that $b^x = o(x^a)$. Meaning that $b^x$ is of higher order that $x^a$.

Q1: What does it mean to have higher order intuitively? Does it mean that one increases/decreases faster than the other one increases/decreases?

Q2: The formel definition have a mathematical structure called an epsilon function.

$$f(x)=\epsilon(x)g(x)$$

What is the epsilon function in my example?

Comment: There are innumerable explanations of this on the web (and of course books).  What did you read and what did you not understand?  Try wikipedia.

Comment: I read the notes my professor have written.  Actually, then thing I have written on internet looks like something else then what I'm reading.

Comment: For $f = o(g),$ think of values of $f$ being (in the limit) $0$ percent of the values of $g$ (the "little $o$" is like multiplying by $0),$ and for $f = O(g),$ think of values of $f$ being (in the limit) some fixed positive (or infinite) percent of the values of $g$ (more correctly, bounded above some fixed positive percent of the values of $g,$ to allow for the fact that the values of $f$ and $g$ do not have to be proportional to each other). For me the little $o$ is easier to remember this way, and I think of big $O$ as a sort of "strictly greater than little $o$" relation.

Comment: Oops, the last part of my previous comment is not correct. $f = O(g)$ is being (in the limit) less than some fixed positive constant times $g.$ Personally, I never liked $o$ or $O,$ and instead I find it much more intuitive to use $f \ll g $ for $f = o(g)$ $(f$ is "infinitely smaller than" $g)$ and $f \approx g$ for "$f = O(g)$ and $g = O(f)$" (neither $f$ is infinitely smaller than $g$ nor $g$ is infinitely smaller than $f),$ not having much use for the uni-directional "big $O$" notion.

Comment: In my first comment I mangled the meaning of $f = O(g)$ and it should be: "... think of values of $f$ being (in the limit) less than some fixed positive (and finite) percent of the values of $g$" (and omit the parenthetical comment that follows). Alternatively, the values of $f$ are NOT (in the limit) *sometimes* infinitely larger than the values of $g$ (where "sometimes" is in the sense that, when taking the limit, we don't want any subsequences where the values of $f$ become infinitely larger than the values of $g,$ even if the other values of $f$ are tiny in comparison to $g).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro  Could you please rewrite your first comment and include all the information in that one. It will be easier to follow what you are saying

Comment: I'll go ahead and write an answer, since no one else has done so (yet), but I won't have the chance until later today or maybe tomorrow.